# Is Liquibase still active in development?

Tags: liquibase

I have seen at [Github](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase) that the last commit was done some months ago and the last release is from 2016. Any ideas if the project is still active?

Comment: The last commit in https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase is about one hour old.

Comment: This was after my question ;-)
But anyway no release since more than 1 year.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liquibase is still in active development. Here is a post from the [Liquibase-Developers forum, dated November 13, 2017](http://forum.liquibase.org/#Topic/49382000001770011).

> Hi,
>
> It's always great to hear from people who find value in and who are
>   actively using Liquibase. I can take a moment to provide some updates
>   regarding the future plans for Liquibase.
>
> To be fully transparent, as of late, I’ve been very committed to other
>   projects and have not been able to make time to contribute to
>   Liquibase. This isn’t how I want things to go, and I agree that
>   updates on Liquibase are overdue. To directly address your question,
>   we do have a plan to push out a release that includes a number of high
>   value pull requests that are currently sitting in review. In all
>   honesty, this is something that will be out early next year (likely in
>   January) as I simply don’t have many spare cycles right now.
>
> Going forward, I know that both myself and the broader team at Datical
>   know we need to do more to keep the Liquibase project moving forward.
>   It’s common for open source efforts to sometimes stagnate or slow, but
>   we certainly don’t want things to come to a halt. As such, you can
>   expect more active maintenance and involvement than there has been of
>   late.
>
> In regards to the the Datical fork, it's not really a fork but simply
>   a branch which will get merged in when I get a chance to make sure it
>   is does not include any changes that will adversely affect other
>   Liquibase users. It will be brought in as part of the 3.6 release.
>
> Lastly, we are spending some time thinking about how we can add more
>   committers to the Liquibase project. When I do get busy, I don’t want
>   to continue to be the sole bottleneck to progress on this project. I
>   don’t have a vetted strategy yet, but I’d look to active, engaged
>   members from the user community to step up and serve as committers.
>   The DBManul merge was a good example of this where a community member
>   was able to go through the work of testing and integrating a large set
>   of pull requests that I was able to bring in a bundle. That was very
>   helpful, but we need something more consistent and organized. As the
>   project and community has grown over the years it has become well past
>   time that I found ways to scale process of accepting pull requests.
>
> Thanks again for being an active user for all these years. I
>   appreciate you sticking with this project, and I hope that you (and
>   others that a part of the Liquibase community) remain with us as we
>   bring development of Liquibase back to a more predictable pace.
>
> Nathan

Comment: Liquibase forum should go [discourse](https://www.discourse.org/)! Just sayin. :-)

Comment: Liquibase itself is open source and has no income, so unless discourse has a free option for open source projects that isn't really feasible. I agree that the ZOHO forums are not very good. They've done something recently that prevents LastPass from logging in correctly, so I have stopped contributing there as much as I used to.

Comment: Discourse is also 100% free and open source but I think you're referring to  a free hosting option - which they don't offer (or at least not that I know). I guess ZOHO does offer free hosting?

Comment: @SteveDonie We consider using Liquibase for the project. Are there any other updates?

Comment: The company that hired Nathan (founder of Liquibase) recently changed its name to Liquibase to indicate their level of commitment to the project, and has been doing all sorts of updates to the project. I am no longer with the company, but still a strong supporter. Check out liquibase.com and liquibase.org. They have also started using discourse for the user forums. https://forum.liquibase.org/